# How to remove last part of a string with different length in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to collect the lines from a file which doesn't start with a # as its first caracter.
I have this code I am able to get them:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    [[ -z "$line" ]] && continue
    [[ "$line" =~ ^# ]] && continue
     #echo "LINEREADED: $line"
done < $file
```

So the output I have is something like this:

```
modules/core_as/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx [100]
```

My question is how can I get only the string without the [100]?

I know there is some commands like sed or trim but the problem is that the string is not always that length, sometimes is different like:

```
cross_modules/core_as/xxxx/xxxxxxxxx [100-103]
```

or

```
cross_modules/core_as/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx [100-103]
```

or anything like  that...

And in all this cases I only need the string without the [....] and without the last blank space at the end of last x, whichever the length of the string is, like cross_modules/core_as/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx

```
echo ${caseReaded:1:${#caseReaded}-7}
```

This also do the job but is not generic for any length.

Does anyone knows how I can get this?

Comment: would help to have some sample lines of input; for lines you want to keep ... are there only the 2x fields separated by a space (as in the single example row)? what do you want to do with the results ... just dump to stdout? or do you need to do something with each line (eg, within a `for` loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip a certain part of a string in bash

```
echo "${line% [*}"
cross_modules/core_as/xxxx/xxxxxxxxx
modules/core_as/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
cross_modules/core_as/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

If the spaces are only before `[`:

```
while IFS= read -r line _
do
    [[ -z $line ]] && continue
    [[ $line =~ ^# ]] && continue
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` to match all lines *not* starting with `#` and then display the first field using `cut`, which works if the first field doesn't contain spaces:

```
grep -v ^# "$file" | cut -f1 -d' '
```

If the thing before `[100]` contains spaces, this may be the way to go:

```
grep -v ^# "$file" | sed -E 's/^(.*) .*$/\1/'
```

The last one works because the `.*` match in `sed` is greedy so only the last space will be left to match the outer condition  `.*$`.